# Need understanding on "Changes in abstract class will not break code for all inheriting classes"

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

1. Please provide your insights, or correct me,  on what is being referred in the statement:
   "when we change code in abstract class all inheriting classes will have this changes. But on changing code in Interface, it breaks the code for all the implementing classes"

When I tried, as below, both of them, abstract class and interface, breaks the code.

I tried creating an abstract class A with method 1(concrete), method 2 (abstract), and created a class B extending class A .
When I try to add another method 3 (abstract) in class A, I see the code breaks in class B (an error - must implement the inherited abstract method).

2. What could be the main objective to have "only abstract methods in an abstract class" and "only concrete methods in an abstract class"?

Answer (score 2):

1 - They mean different kinds of changes: when they say "all inheriting classes will have this changes" they must be talking about non-breaking changes, such as altering an implementation of a method, adding fields, writing additional private non-abstract methods, and so on. Some changes could be breaking, such as writing non-private methods, because existing classes may have methods by the same name, but returning a different thing, or implementing a different functionality.

On the other hand, interfaces consist of method declarations, so most changes to them would be breaking (some changes are non-breaking, for example, renaming method's formal parameters in the interface).

In Java-8 you can also provide default implementations for a method. Changing default implementation is a non-breaking change - the code will continue to compile.

2 - An abstract class with only abstract methods and no data members serves no legitimate purpose. In comparison to an interface, it reduces flexibility of the code using it, because subclasses are unable to inherit any other class.

Answer (score 1):

1. For the first question

Even I'm not sure what this line exactly means but here is my interpretation of this. An abstract class can have both abstract and concrete methods what the first statements refers to adding new concrete methods or changing parameters of the existing concrete methods, those changes will be reflected in all the inheriting classes.

By default all methods in interfaces are abstract and it is the requirement that each implementing class should either define each method of the interface or make it abstract. Now in the second statement by breaking the code it means that if we make changes to the methods of the interface corresponding changes are supposed to be made to the implementation methods also ex. Changing the parameters of the method in interface

2. For the second question,

   - "only abstract methods in an abstract class" ->  I can't find a valid reason to do this as an abstract class with all abstract methods is pretty useless while an interface would be more flexible.
   - "only concrete methods in an abstract class" ->  One reason to do this is if you are trying to implement something like a "Template Method Design Pattern". You can google around it and get detailed info on this.
     Another reason can be to avoid its instantiating it directly  (which I strongly believe should not be done :p).

I hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

> Need understanding on “Changes in abstract class will not break code
>   for all inheriting classes”

There's no dichotomy.

With inheritance in Java, a subclass (or implementing class) gets at least two things:

- A contract (specified by its API)
- Implementation (formerly available only with abstract classes, but now also available as default interface methods in Java 8+)

It is typically true that an API developer is free to change the implementation provided by an abstract class **ONLY AS LONG AS** such changes do not change the contract specified by its API.  If this happens, then yes, changing the implementation will cause clients to break.

At no point, however, can an API developer change the contract -- whether it has been specified by an abstract class or an interface -- and not expect clients to break.  In Java 7 and earlier, interfaces could only express the contract with abstract method signatures ... so changing any of these would break clients.

Even so, even in Java 7, an abstract class author could evolve method implementations without penalty (even add new methods) but only if the original contract specified by the abstract class was still valid.

Answer (score 0):

1. If there are lot of methods in the contract, then the abstract class is more useful because we can provide a default implementation for some of the methods that are common for all the sub-classes. Also, if sub-classes don’t need to implement a particular method, they can avoid providing the implementation but in the case of an interface, the subclass will have to provide an implementation for all the methods even though it’s of no use and implementation is just empty block.
2. If our base contract keeps on changing then interfaces can cause issues because we can’t declare additional methods to the interface without changing all the implementation classes, with an abstract class we can provide the default implementation and only change the implementation classes that are actually going to use the new methods.

Answer (score 0):

Adding new method to existing abstract class will break all child classes that depend on it. Consider breaking down your main abstract class into multiple abstract classes.